# Box shadow animation on SVG element

Tags: svg, css-animations, css

Is there any option to animate CSS box-shadow effect on SVG element?
I have this markup:

```
<g id="g-svg_el_obj921" style="top: 300px; left: 550px;">
  <circle r="95.12" fill="rgb(50, 149, 196)" class="some_class" id="svg_el_obj921" priority="4" position="300_550" cx="550" cy="300"></circle>
</g>
```

and this animation setup:

```
circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: shadow_fly 310ms infinite ease-in-out;

  @-webkit-keyframes shadow_fly {
    0% {-webkit-svg-shadow: 0 0 7px #53BE12;}
    50% {-webkit-svg-shadow: 0 0 30px #53BE12;}
    99% {-webkit-svg-shadow: 0 0 7px #53BE12;}
  }

  &:hover {
  }
}
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes filters can be animated:
[Here](http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/6eca814eda8ec7e758d0feab628bd390?editors=110) is how to create shadow/inset/blur filters on svg

```html
<svg id="obj921">
  <filter id="imagenconturbulencias" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
  <feTurbulence result="cloud" baseFrequency=".01" seed="1" stitchTiles="nostitch" type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="2">
  
  <animate attributeName="baseFrequency" calcMode="paced" begin="0s" dur="12s" values=".01;.13;.01;" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </feTurbulence>
  <feComposite operator="in" in="cloud" in2="SourceGraphic"/></filter>
  

  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>

<svg>
  <use filter="url(#imagenconturbulencias)" xlink:href="#obj921"></use>
</svg>
```

run this snippet!

*[animate/>](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#PresentationTime) tag goes inside filter/> description tag /look closely*

The circle in < use > tag is the animated one, you have to hide the original sprite as smart as you can. That is common task in using sprites - advantage for this approach is, you can reference {use} this sprite in many places over your page, but it's vector values are loaded once (that saves space)

Answer (score 0):

There is not, at least with css-animation, it's only possible for html elements, not svg elements.